# How to create a service in my app that will run only when user opens WhatsApp Application

Tags: java, android, xml, service

I'm trying my hands on services in android. I want to create a basic application where a service should run in background and when user opens WhatsApp or some X application, my service should run automatically.

For example I need to make a service to show a Toast "You opened whatsapp" when user opens the WhatsApp application.

How can I do this?

Comment: Yeah you can probably do it.

Comment: Can you help me with any code or reference?

Comment: did you tried anything yourself? what was issue you faced while doing?

Comment: I tried the below answer and it is no longer working on Android L and higher, any alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the process is running (alive) e.g.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
        {
            if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.whatsapp")) //Check this up
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WhatsApp is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: not working, tried with com.whatsapp package name too